# Query string order by custom field

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, query-string

I have code for custom post type, for custom taxonomy for displaying category posts. I am using Advanced Custom Fields

What I want is to order posts by custom field value, and I was wondering how I can do it?

For example if posts have custom field called “rating” how can I order posts from lowest value to highest?

Here's an example code

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'brendovi' ) ); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()): query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=date&order=ASC');  ?>
            <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

This is the code that works just fine for displaying most recent custom post type posts, and they have custom fields called field_1, field_2, field_3. And users will fill those fields with numeric value. And later on on single post, I'll do the calculation summing those values and dividing by 3 to get avg value.
Let's call it field_4.

I am stuck at displaying posts and sorting them by that field_4 with query string.

Perhaps I don't need query string?

Comment: Please share your code, what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: [WP_Query Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: Don't use `query_posts()`. Use the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/).

Comment: @Jacob cab you provide me with sample code for my case?

Answer (score 0):

The `query_posts` is only useful when you actually know what you are doing.
Base on the info you provide this should work for you :

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'your_cpt',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,//get them all
    'meta_key'          => 'field_4',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

        $class = get_field('field_4');

        ?>
        <li <?php echo $class; ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data  ?>
```